# How can I check if an environmental variable is set?

Tags: string, perl, environment-variables

I have the following code in perl

```
my %Opt = 
  (
   boards_txt => "$ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'}/hardware/arduino/boards.txt",
  );
```

In this you can see that the env variable `ARDUINO_DIR` is append. Some users might not have this variable set. If that is the case, then I want to hardcode a path.

Question: How can I check if the env variable is set or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using the `%ENV` hash. It contains all environment variables, so you could do something like:

```
if (defined $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'}) { $prefix = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'} }
else { $prefix = '/path/to/arduino/dir/' }

my $path_to_txt = $prefix . 'boards.txt';
```

I suggest you use `File::Spec` for working with paths.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answers have been given, but I wanted to add that you might make use of the rather handy [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) assignment operator `//=`:

```
my $dir = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'};  
$dir //= "/other/path";
```

Or, as [RobEarl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691146/robearl) points out in the comment:

```
my $dir = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'} // "/other/path";
```

This is the logical equivalent of

```
my $dir;
if (defined $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'}) { 
    $dir = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'};
} else {
    $dir = "/other/path";
}
```

As [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) points out, the defined-or operator requires perl v5.10. For those who still have not upgraded to that version it is also possible to use the `||` operator:

```
my $dir = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'} || "/other/path";
```

The caveat being that this will overwrite values that are interpreted as false, which may in some context be considered proper values, such as the empty string or zero. In this case, however, it is unlikely that `0` or the empty string are valid paths.

Comment: or just `my $dir = $ENV{'ARDUINO_DIR'} // "/other/path";`

Comment: Handy for anyone using Perl v5.10 or better.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for existence of a hash key with `exists`:

```
perl -le 'print "fnord!" if exists $ENV{"ARDUINO_DIR"}'
```

Comment: ...though I'd be more inclined to use `length` in this situation

Comment: Yup. `exists` is a required, but not a sufficient criterion. The key may exist, but its value still be undefined, in which case the env var would not be set.